# How to push objects in AngularJS right below the element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recusativ tree... I get it from laravel api. Problem is when I push object it don't go below the comment I want reply, it go on the end.

Here is my directive:

`el` is current element inside `ng-repeat`, I need below that element to add new one.

This part: `scope.comments.push(data);` will push element on the end of `ng-repeat`

```
.directive("addreplys", function($compile,commentFactory){
            return {
              link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                 // I contain the ngModel values for form interaction.
                scope.form = {
                    reply: ""
                };

                //CALL FACTORY TO ADD NEW REPLAY
                scope.addReply = function(el) {

                    commentFactory.saveComment(scope.form.reply[el.pivot.comment_id],el.pivot.project_id,el.pivot.comment_id,el.level+1)
                            .success(function(data){
                                //ADD REPLY TO CLIENT SIDE
                                scope.comments.push(data);
                            })
                            .error(function(data){
                               console.log(data); 
                            });
                    // Reset the form once values have been consumed.
                 scope.form.reply = "";
                };
              }
            };
          });
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are you talking about **reply of a comment** ?

Comment: Yes.... Is something wrong with my code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**push** always pushes items to the end of an array.
use **unshift** instead of push

Ok, then look:
1. find the index "idx" of the current document in the array:

**allComments.indexOf(currentDocument)**

2. splice the the newObject into the array

**allComments.splice(idx + 1, 0, newObject)**

finalCode

```
allComments.splice(allComments.indexOf(currentDocument) + 1, 0, newObject)
```

Comment: It will put my object on the beginning of all comments not below current comment...

Answer (score 0):

You can use unshift, the element will be at the start of the array:

[see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

ex:

> var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
>
> a.unshift(0);

```
//  a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.0/angular.js"></script>
<body>


    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <!--Comment section-->
        <ul ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index" style="background: skyblue; padding: 10px;">
            <li>
                <b>Comment {{$index}} : </b>
                <br>
                {{comment.comment}}
                <!--Reply section-->
                    <ul ng-repeat="reply in comment.reply track by $index">
                        <li><i>Reply {{$index}} :</i><br>
                            {{reply.comment}}</li>
                    </ul>
                <!--End reply section-->
                <input type="text" ng-model="reply" placeholder=" Write your reply." /><a href="" ng-click="insertReply($index,reply)">Reply</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--End comment section -->
            

        <!--Post your comment-->
        <b>New comment</b>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your comment" ng-model="comment" />
        <a href="" ng-click="newComment(comment)">Post </a>
    </div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            //Comments object having reply oject
            $scope.comments = [{ comment: 'hi', reply: [{ comment: 'hi inside commnet' }, { comment: 'hi inside commnet' }] }];

            //push reply
            $scope.insertReply = function (index, reply) {
                $scope.comments[index].reply.push({ comment: reply });
            }

            //push commnet
            $scope.newComment = function (comment) {
                $scope.comments.push({ comment: comment, reply: [] });
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```